# Traversal from Different Sources to Same Target

Tags: java, groovy, tinkerpop

I have the following graph layout:

[image]

I am trying to get to the `TargetVertex` and I am given three other vertices `Vertex1`, `Vertex2`, and `Vertex3`.

I have to use all three source vertices to ensure that the target one in the end is the same amongst all 3.

I believe the groovy syntax may be something of the form :

```
g.V(Vertex1.id, Vertex2.id, Vertex3.id).branch(id()).
    option(Vertex1.id(), in().V()).
    option(Vertex2.id(), in().V()).
    option(Vertex3.id(), out().V());
```

An example of this sort of traversal from multiple sources to the same target would be very appreciated. More specifically, I am looking for a traversal where the end result is guaranteed be the same (i.e. `TargetVertex`) regardless of the source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a problem to be solved with `branch()`. Start with one of the vertices and verify that the other 2 vertices are connected:

```
g.V(v3).out().and(out().is(v1), out().is(v2))
```

Another option would be the `match()` step:

```
g.V(v3).match(
     __.as("a").out().as("t"),
     __.as("t").out().is(v1),
     __.as("t").out().is(v2)).select("t")
```

The former will be faster though. In both cases it's the same code in Java and Groovy.

Comment: Hi Daniel. I have tried your method and it appears to work. I have voted up and will mark correct after further testing.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have it pretty much correct already. Below is an example to construct and query the graph you proposed that you can try out in a TinkerPop3 Gremlin Console:

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerGraph.open()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]
gremlin> vt = graph.addVertex(); v1 = graph.addVertex(); v2 = graph.addVertex(); v3 = graph.addVertex()
==>v[3]
gremlin> vt.addEdge('to', v1); vt.addEdge('to', v2); v3.addEdge('to', vt)
==>e[6][3-to->0]
gremlin> v1.id()
==>1
gremlin> v2.id()
==>2
gremlin> v3.id()
==>3
gremlin> vt.id()
==>0
gremlin> g.V().branch(id()).option(v1.id(), __.in().id()).option(v2.id(), __.in().id()).option(v3.id(), __.out().id())
==>0
==>0
==>0
```

You can see that 3 traversers complete the path, and all lead to the target vertex with id 0. In my query, I didn't restrict the `g.V()` to the 3 starting nodes, so a traverser actually starts on the target node, but since it doesn't match any of the options, that traverser dies.

Comment: I am going to try this out in java. Looks promising. However does this approach guarantee that all the traversals will hit `vt`. What if `v1` has an edge to `vt2` ? Won't this approach return `vt`, `vt2`, `vt`, and `vt` ? I am kind of looking for a result which guarantees all the traversals hit the same target ? Formally I am looking for an intersection of the 3 options.

Comment: Oh, I see. If you want to restrict to only the target vertex, you could adjust the option clauses like `option(v1.id(), __.in().hasId(vt.id()))`.

Comment: I just tried your solution out and it does return the list but does not ensure that it's the same vertex. With regards to adjusting the options clause I can't do that since I don't know `vt`. Essentially I need to intersect the three options and that will (at least in my case) lead me to `vt`. Is there a way of intersecting the results returned by your `g.V().branch(id()).option(v1.id(), __.in().id()).option(v2.id(), __.in().id()).option(v3.id(), __.out().id())` ?